# How to use a Postgreql Boolean value as a parameter in a python if statement?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, if-statement, boolean

I have been trying to create a python function that will use a select statement that will return a single Boolean value from my postgres database and then use it in a python if statement.

I have found out that when you print the result of the sql select statemtent the format is `[(True,)]`. However, nothing that I have tried putting in the python if statement has not worked.
I have tried:

```
True
"True"
"[(True,)]"
"[(" + str(True) + ",)]"
```

and none of these have worked and I can't really think of what else it could be.

The sql statement I am executing is

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT is_draft FROM item_pool WHERE item_id = " + str(item_id) + " ", {})
list_of_tuples = cur.fetchall()
conn.close()
return list_of_tuples
```

And I want to check if the is_draft Boolean that is returned is True in python.

Comment: Please would you share your code and error ?

Comment: I've added a code snippet, but I have no error. I just can't find a way to recognize the Boolean

Comment: 1) What is the type for `is_draft` in the table? 2) Do not build queries this way, use [Parameter Passing](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) 3) Assuming the `... WHERE item_id = ` returns a single result then `if cur.fetchone()[0]: ...`

Comment: `is_draft` is a boolean and I can't use `cur.fetchone()[0]` in the if statement since the Select statement is in its own method because the `is_draft` boolean is needed in multiple different methods.

Comment: Nevermind, you were right about using `cur.fetchone(0)`, but instead of putting in the if statement I just returned the first element of the tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python

your function would return

```
return cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

which would return `TRUE` or `FALSE`

for a query like

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROMmytable WHERE id = -1)
```